# windows pdcurses win32a non-english keyboard

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-layout, pdcurses

When using the pdcurses windows port win32a (link [here](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm)) I'm having trouble getting my non-english (in this case swedish) keyboard to work with characters outside the 0-9, a-z and A-Z range.

Example: pressing `shift + 2` generates `@` instead of `"` which would be perfectly acceptable if I were using an american keyboard (but I'm not).

I'm compiling on windows using Visual Studio 2010, C++.

Also, if I try to compile a regular console application then the keyboardlayot is recognised correctly on the command promt.

Comment: MS have a port of ncurses. Consider using NCurses for the windows port.